# Slight Blue Tint On Right-Half Of Screen

Tags: display, desktop-computer

So I've been dealing with an ongoing issue that I'm hoping someone can help me solve. I purchased a BenQ PD2700Q and noticed that images on the right-side of the screen were slightly bluer than on the left. Thinking it was an issue with the monitor I sent it back and picked up a ASUS PB278Q to use temporarily. However I'm noticing the same issue and I've pretty much run out of ideas.

Here's what I've tired.

- Switched out the cables.
- Switched from DP to DVI.
- Tried all three DP slots on my RX 480.
- Switched out my RX 480 with an older RX 370.
- Again switched out all the cables.
- Again switched from DP to DVI.
- Swithced out my RX 480 for an GTX 760.
- Again switched out all the cables.
- Again switched from DP to DVI.

It seems no matter what I try, the issue is still present. Because it can't be captured in a screenshot I took a picture with my phone, I apologize for the quality. To be honest, I have no idea what side is the correct color at this point, I've found that my eyes are less strained when reading text on the right when compared to the left.

[image: pic of monitor]

Hopefully someone has an answer to this perplexing issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies usually in LVDS cable connecting the panel to the main board. Clean and check. Might aswell switch and check. I have come across this problem and cleaning did work, Though it returned later so I am going to switch the cable now.